# How can Mongoose Populate not working with Array of ObjectIds?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, objectid

I'm trying to populate a mongoose query with an array of objectId field.
In another field with single objectId ref is working fine.

That's my "User" model:

```
const User = new Schema({
    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type:String,
        required: true 
    }
})
mongoose.model('users',User)
```

That's my "Pedido" model:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

    const Pedido = new Schema({
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        cliente: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'clientes',
            required: true 
        },       
        fotografos: {
            type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
            ref: 'users'
        }            

    })
    mongoose.model('pedidos',Pedido)
```

my router:

```
router.get('/pedidos',async(req,res)=>{
      var query = await Pedido.find().populate('fotografos').populate('cliente').lean().exec()
      console.log(query)
      res.render("admin/pedidos",{pedidos: query})

})
```

That's the result in the console.log:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5e8e3bd16c57021f682b8e81,
    fotografos: [],
    cliente: {
      _id: 5e8ccceea8a28146d86f4cac,
      nome: 'Neymar',
      email: 'neymar@ney.com',
      __v: 0
    },
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

fotografos field (array) are returning empty. 
clientes field returns populated.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this code...**

```
fotografos:[{
            type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
            ref: 'users'
        }]          


**Then do Populate**
```

Comment: Perfect! That's it! Thank you!